# Pg up//Pg dn not scrolling in Skyrim's Console Command panel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

### It's always worked fine, but when I decided to play today it wasn't working..

**How I discovered it**::

I found my follower had 800+ Ebony Arrows on him, I don't play "*OP*", so when I was trying to take a couple hundred of them away I went to search `help "Ebony Arrow"` to get the ID and I couldn't scroll up through the results with the PageUp key.

Never happened before be it just wasn't responding. but I know that mods literally can not effect the Console Command panel, so I doubt it's any of my mods. But it's kinda irritating. **Please Help**!?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the game? Might have been a one-off bug.

Comment: I did when it first happened with no change. But I did try just typing in `help`, it still wouldn't let me Pg up//Pg dn however it said `IsFlyingMountFastTravelling` Dunno why, as I don't have a flying mount. And I haven't seen that before, that I can recall.

Comment: 800 hours later, and I didn't know you could scroll (which had bothered me a large number of times)... -_-

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with running skyrim on a laptop. If that's the case, the only solution I've been able to find in to get another usb keyboard to connect to your laptop. If you're not playing on a laptop, or can't get a usb keyboard, then I honestly have no other solutions.

I've been trying to find a solution to this as well.

Answer (score -3):

Did you try using the mouse wheel / arrow keys?

And here's the command to delete ebony arrows

```
Removeitem 000139BF <#>
```

Then put the number of arrows you wanna remove where the # is and also remove these before you enter it in < >...

Click on the your follower in the console then type this command in